# Why doesn't -fvisibility hide symbols in .so file?

Tags: clang, export, symbols, .so, ghidra

I've tried searching through existing answers, but didn't find anything that helps with this exact situation, so here goes ...

I'm working on a project with a deliverable .so file that contains a lot of proprietary IP, so we want to tightly control the export symbols that it exposes.  Examining the .so with the nm and objdump tools actually shows no symbols exposed (which seems a bit odd, as a client app is able to link with it), but opening it with Ghidra shows absolutely everything imaginable in the 'Exports' tree.

The project is C/C++ code being built in Visual Studio 2019, using the Clang 5.0 toolset (release build for ARM64, android-27).  Perhaps important to note that the library exposes a C API, so none of the functions/structs/enums intended to be exposed are namespaced.  The `-fvisibility=hidden` switch is being set, which I understand *should* hide symbols by default, and `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` is being specified only on the functions we want to expose.  But it doesn't appear to be working as expected.

As a sanity-check experiment, I hacked the code to change the `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` to `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))`, just to see what effect that would have, and was pleasantly relieved to see that the relevant functions no longer appeared in the Ghidra view.  This suggests that we *could* use that to hide things we don't want exposed, but:

1. It's just not really feasible to go through the entire codebase to retrofit that everywhere.
2. Surely that shouldn't be necessary because the `-fvisibility=hidden` switch should be doing that as the default for everything in the library.

For comparison, there is a Windows DLL build of the same project, which declares `__declspec(dllexport)` in the relevant places (usual approach of using a macro to handle the various different build scenarios), and when examining the DLL in Ghidra, only the relevant functions that we want exposed are visible as being exported.

I just want the .so build to do the same thing, but can't seem to make it happen.

As a last-ditch effort, I tried using the `llvm-strip` tool to try removing symbols from the .so file after building, but to no avail (probably because the other tools didn't actually list any symbols in the first place).

Any advice would be gratefully received!